# What are the file types that can be previewed safelly in browsers?

Tags: image, cross-browser

You can preview an image after selecting it to upload as [stated on other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded).

My question is: What image formats are safe to be display in all browsers? 
Note that IE <= 7 is not a browser.

And the more important question is: Where did you found this information?

Comment: Nothing. Users can be tricked into divulging their username/password while viewing nothing more than HTML. This question is too broad to be answered.

Comment: @meagar I don't get how social engineering or even security is related to this question. By "safely" I mean without any errors, as Cedric Simon answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image support depends on browser type, version, and possibly OS too.

If you want to be sure it will be supported by all browser, use JPG or GIF. These are old standard supported by all browsers. PNG is also supported by all modern browsers.

More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support).